# I know unplugging a raspberry without shutting down property is a sin, so what do I do if it's frozen and nothing is responding?

Tags: shutdown

I know unplugging a raspberry without shutting down property is a sin, so what do I do if it's frozen and nothing is responding?

I waited about 10 minutes and it's still stuck.

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4
I was transferring some files to an external hard drive when it froze. The Mouse and keyboard wasn't responding.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The answer depends on whether you are using the Raspberry Pi OS or Ubuntu, and which version. Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1324516/edit) with the new information. If you are using Raspberry Pi OS, then see [this discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=254702)

Comment: Well, it's a forgivable sin. There is pennance you must do afterward (a filesystem check - fsck). It risks data loss. But if your system is frozen, then we have all needed to unplug at some time.

Comment: 10 minutes may not be long, depending on what it was doing...  SysRq commands go direct to the kernel bypassing and user-space programs (including the GUI) that may have frozen allowing a safe shutdown; you can also sometimes `ssh` in from remote to explore & shutdown the box gracefully... but I'd opt for using SysRq and commands on the device direct to the kernel.  You provided no detail on what is doing; for some tasks 10 minutes is not long at all (I often leave machines overnight or 36 hours before I sysrq) - but I don't know what you were doing.